# Executing R Script in Unix with parameters

Tags: r, unix, parameters, arguments

In the Unix script, is there any way to run R files but with arguments in the Unix script?

I know that to run R files in that system, you will need to type "R -f "file" but what codes do you need in R so that you will need to type this instead on Unix:

"R -f "file" arg1 arg2"

Comment: I edited the questions now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.  Save this code in test.R:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
# make this script executable by doing 'chmod +x test.R'
help = cat(
"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Help text here
Arguments in this order:
    1) firstarg
    2) secondarg
    3) thirdarg
    4) fourtharg
./test.R firstarg secondarg thirdarg fourtharg
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\n\n")

# Read options from command line
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
if(is.element("--help", args) | is.element("-h", args) | is.element("-help", args) | is.element("--h", args)){
    cat(help,sep="\n")
    stop("\nHelp requested.")
}

print(args)
```

Do `chmod +x test.R`
Then invoke it using `./test.R a b c d`. It should print: `[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"`.

You can access each of the args by doing `args[1]` to get to `a` and `args[4]` to get to `d`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use Rscript does seem useful but possibly not what is being asked. One can also start R from the command line with an input file that gets sourced. The R interpreter can access the commandArgs in that mode as well. This is a minimal "ptest.R" file in my user directory that is also my default working directory:

```
ca <- commandArgs()
print(ca)
```

From a Unix command line I can do:

```
$ r -f ~/ptest.r --args "test of args"
```

And R opens, displays the usual startup messages and announces packages loaded by `.Rprofile` and then:

```
> ca <- commandArgs()
> print(ca)
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R"
[2] "-f"                                                  
[3] "/Users/davidwinsemius/ptest.r"                       
[4] "--args"                                              
[5] "test of args"                                        
> 
>
```

And then quits.